# Getting Polyline ID Clicked

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I'm using Google Maps v3 and have a map placed on my page.  The user selects a bunch of data from some lists and then my map is updated with data from my db and provides the user with a map with a polyline of the selected data.  The data is retrieved from the db using jquery and returned as json.  My code parses the json and draws the polyline. My json contains a data ID, lat, lng. Works fine.

Now I want the user to be able to click on one of the polyline points and I will get additional data for that data ID from my database, but I'm having trouble identifying which ID they clicked.  Does anyone have a quick solution to identifying which id was clicked on the line?

This is my listener for the polyline click event.  It can get it to react just fine but I don't know how to identify "what" point was clicked so that I can go get my additional data.  The example below gives me the ID of the first element in my polyline so I know I'm accessing the array and the event is firing.  Just need to be able to locate the specific point I clicked.
I get my json.  My test set has 8,349 points that looks like this.

```js
{
            "id": 1590065,
            "lat": 37.07318,
            "lng": -88.563132}
,{
            "id": 1590066,
            "lat": 37.07307,
            "lng": -88.563002}
,{
            "id": 1590067,
            "lat": 37.072967,
            "lng": -88.562875}
,{
            "id": 1590068,
            "lat": 37.07287,
            "lng": -88.56275}
,{
            "id": 1590069,
            "lat": 37.072779,
            "lng": -88.56263}
,....
```

Then I parse the data and assign it to my coordinates.

```js
vesselPathCoordinates = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]");
```

Then I build my polyline.

```js
vesselPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: vesselPathCoordinates,
    strokeColor: ''#FF0000'',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1.5
});



google.maps.event.addListener(vesselPath, 'click', function( event ){
      console.log( vesselPathCoordinates[0].id ); 
        });
```

When the user click a specific point on the line I want to know what ID from the JSON that they clicked.  In other words, what lat and lng point on the line triggered the event.

Comment: Sorry. "vesselPath" is my polyline and "vesselPathCoordinates" is my coordinate array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fine the closest point in the line to the clicked point, look up the id of that vertex in the input data and return it.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(vesselPath, 'click', function( event ){
  console.log(event);
  var minDist = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  for (var i=0; i<this.getPath().getLength(); i++){
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(event.latLng, this.getPath().getAt(i));
    if (distance < minDist) {
      minDist = distance;
      index = i;
    }
  }
  infowindow.setContent("id="+vesselPathCoordinates[index].id);
  infowindow.setPosition(this.getPath().getAt(index));
  infowindow.open(map);
  console.log( vesselPathCoordinates[0].id ); 
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  vesselPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: vesselPathCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1.5,
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < vesselPath.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(vesselPath.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  google.maps.event.addListener(vesselPath, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    var minDist = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(event.latLng, this.getPath().getAt(i));
      if (distance < minDist) {
        minDist = distance;
        index = i;
      }
    }
    infowindow.setContent("id=" + vesselPathCoordinates[index].id);
    infowindow.setPosition(this.getPath().getAt(index));
    infowindow.open(map);
    console.log(vesselPathCoordinates[index].id);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var vesselPathCoordinates = [{
  "id": 1590065,
  "lat": 37.07318,
  "lng": -88.563132
}, {
  "id": 1590066,
  "lat": 37.07307,
  "lng": -88.563002
}, {
  "id": 1590067,
  "lat": 37.072967,
  "lng": -88.562875
}, {
  "id": 1590068,
  "lat": 37.07287,
  "lng": -88.56275
}, {
  "id": 1590069,
  "lat": 37.072779,
  "lng": -88.56263
}]
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  declare a  function for adding the listenr to you polyline passing the date you need in event

```
var addListenersOnPolyline = function(polyline, myJsonData) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function (event) {
        window.open(myJsonData.myData);

    });
```

and when you nedd you can set the event by  the function this way

```
addListenersOnPolyline(myActPolyline, myActJsonData );
```

If you have

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(yourJson);
jsonData.id // should contain 1590065
```

Comment: So you're suggesting adding a listener for each point?  My datasets can contain anywhere from 1 to [x], i.e. thousands,  points.

Comment: I use this technique even with 50,000 polygons simultaneously visible on the map and they work fine. For what i know is  the normal technique per object event management in google maps ..

Comment: I suggest you an event for polyline ... why you are thinking to point?

Comment: Ok.  This stuff is all pretty new to me, but it just doesn't seem that efficient, but I will give it a go.

Comment: I very very efficient .. is javascript

Comment: I'm missing something.  Used your code above and replaced window.open with console.log(myJsonDate).  When I click a point on my line I get the entire json returned in the console and not the specific point I clicked.  How do I get the single point that I clicked?

Comment: In my sample MyJsonData is not all the Json file but only the data portion for the specific polyline

Comment: I have json like this.  {
            "id": 1590065,
            "lat": 37.07318,
            "lng": -88.563132}
,{
            "id": 1590066,
            "lat": 37.07307,
            "lng": -88.563002} and my line is drawn.  Listener is google.maps.event.addListener(vesselPath, ''click'', addListenersOnPolyline(vesselPath, vesselPathCoordinates ));  Function is var addListenersOnPolyline = function(polyline, myJsonData) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, ''click'', function (event) {
        console.log(myJsonData);
    })};    How do I get the ID of the point I click?

Comment: I'm missing the bit of how to attach a listener to each point.

Comment: What do you mean whit each point? a polyline or each single coord of the polyline .. and way do you refer to point and not to the polyline?

Comment: Yes, that gets me the id of the first point.  What if I click point 2,127?  How do I get the ID of that point?

Comment: If you can update your original question with a bit of code where you retrieve the Json, create the polyline  and add the listener so i can see hat are you doing..

Comment: Updated the question with a bit more as you requested.

Comment: But vesselPath is polyline and then you have only one listener for the object polyline  .. if you want manage event click fo every singlle point/coord of the polyline you must add a marker for each point and for each marker add specific listener .so when you click the specific marker you get the point you need (and if you preserve  a proper id you get the segment of polyline) . otherwise you can't control the single point click event because you have not the proper  "listener"

Comment: Ok, I think that was the answer I was looking for!  I'll have to do some work to get that in place and will let you know the outcome.  Thanks.